# If else condition always excuting else not if

Tags: iphone, if-statement

i am using if else to see the condition but it always execute else

```
int mytestcount=rowCount;
NSLog(@"My Test ROw Count IS %d",mytestcount);


if (mytestcount=0) {


    NSLog("No Data To Upload");

}


else {


    [Coffee getInitialDataToDisplay:[self getDBPath]];



}
```

my if is true then also it excutes else i do not know why when rowCount is 0

Comment: You have typed `mytestcount=0` instead of `mytestcount == 0`

Comment: Please think and research before posting your questions, this was quite a general one... :)

Comment: This should have given you a warning that says "Using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses" and if clicked the warning will allow you to add Parentheses or add ==. Use warnings to your advantage and research your questions as this is basic programming skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

= is the assignment operator, == is the comparison operator.
So your code fragment:

- assigns 0 to mytestcount
- uses mytestcount in the if-condition, and since mytestcount equals 0 and C-based languages treat 0 as false, your if condition always evaluates to false, and your else branch is always executed

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you need to add another = sign so that it reads:

```
if (mytestcount==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int mytestcount=rowCount;
 NSLog(@"My Test ROw Count IS %d",mytestcount);


if (mytestcount == 0) {


NSLog("No Data To Upload");

}


 else {


[Coffee getInitialDataToDisplay:[self getDBPath]];



}
```

Check it out...

Answer (score 0):

You statement `(mytestcount = 0)` is actually, assigning `0` to `mytestcount`, then using the value of `mytestcount` as the boolean expression, which will always be false since it is being assigned the value of `0`.

This is an extremely common typo, so much so that most compilers can detect this happening and print a warning message when it recognizes this pattern, since you almost always will not intend that behaviour.

**You should consider running gcc with** `-Wall -Werror`, this will cause the compiler to throw an error if it see's common patterns for these and other similar mistakes.